# Java get CodeSigners from class

Tags: java

I'm running java 17 and calling `class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getSigners()` always returns null even though the associated jar is correctly signed. Does anyone know why this is and if there is a fix or another solution.

When checking the jarsigner the following gets returned,  jarsigner -verify .\mcpaintball-1.5.1-R.jar

jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is invalid. Reason: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate is self-signed.

Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.

I have tried to use both `class.getSigners()` and `class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getCertificates()` to no avail.
I was expecting to get the list of signers containing my signing information or at the very least the certificate.

Are there algorithms that java does not support that could be causing this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the class from the signed JAR file? If you're testing in an IDE you won't be.

Comment: What's your evidence? How did you find how the class was loaded? What was the result of `getCodeSource()`?

Comment: (union:/E:/CurseForge/Instances/mcp/mods/mcpaintball-1.5.1-R.jar%23157!/ <no signer certificates>) that is the result. It is a minecraft mod that im working on

Comment: So that JAR file doesn't have a signer certificate. Java just told you so. So sign it.

Comment: Well Java doesn't agree with you, and neither do I.

Comment: I have added the jarsigner -verify output in the question. Does that look correct or is my self-signed certificate not correctly formatted to be used for code signing.

Comment: @Multicoder Are you using a self-signed certificate? Seems like it's not trusted by your system.Try adding the certificate to the truststore.

Comment: @DASH which trust store should I use, Trusted publishers or a different one. I have imported into both Trusted publishers and Trusted Root CA. After running jarsigner verify again. the same output gets printed

Comment: @Multicoder try adding it to the default java trststore file "cacerts.jks".

Comment: @DASH How would I go about adding the certificate into that jks file, Im on windows 11 for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding the self-signed cert which was used to sign the jar to your systems truststore.

Export certificate from the JAR file

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <signer> -keystore <keystore.jks> -storepass <password> -file signer.cer
```

Import to truststore

```
keytool -importcert -alias <signer> -keystore <cacerts.jks> -storepass <password> -file signer.cer
```

Replace values in brackets accordingly. keytool is available in jdk, so should work in windows.
After this verify signature.

It’s possible that your cacerts file is not in the JKS format.
The cacerts file is usually located in the
`$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/` directory.

You can check the format of your cacerts file using the following command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/cacerts
```

If cacerts file is not in the JKS format, you can convert it to JKS using the following command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /path/to/cacerts -destkeystore /path/to/cacerts.jks -deststoretype jks
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Multicoder updated answer. Adding cert to truststore is a quite standered process. You can easily search and find out the commands and procedure.

Comment: @Multicoder I think that's normal for self-signed certs. If you want to get rid of it, then you'll need to use a cert signed by a trusted authority.

Comment: all that is causing me trouble now is the class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getSigners() that is returning null instead of the signature
https://gist.github.com/DDX5/57aa0e99e3366cf9c5121ae6d80c6b7d that is the class I'm using to get this

Comment: @Multicoder It is because self-signed certificates are not trusted by the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). The JRE only trusts certificates that have been signed by a trusted certificate authority.

Comment: So the way I'm doing this would never work then and only used to work as I has the same feature in Java 8 @DASH

Comment: If you want to get signers as not null ,you'll have to go with a cert signed by trusted CA. Tools like OpenSSL can be used to extract the certificate chain from the self-signed certificate, and the signers can be found in the chain. Other than that i have no clue.